# Delete annotation from figure

Tags: matlab, annotations

I have a gui that includes a plot. In this plot I add an annotation. When the plot data is changed using the gui, he old annotation remains and the new one is plotted over the old on.

So I need to remove he old annotation.
I tried the following code, but that has no effect:

```
set(0,'showhiddenhandles','on')
% look for all axes in the figure of choice:
h_all_axes = findall(gcf,'type','axes');
% get the 'annotation layer' axes handle:
h_anno_axes = double(find(handle(h_all_axes),'-class','graph2d.annotationlayer'));
delete(h_anno_axes);
set(0,'showhiddenhandles','off');

annotationPos = [0.55 0.58 0.6 0.3];
htxtbox = annotation('textbox',annotationPos, ...
    'String'     ,strtextbox, ...
    'FontSize'   ,FontSize+1, ...
    'FitBoxToText', 'on', ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
    'FontName'   , 'Courier New');
```

Comment: can't you save the handle to the previous annotation (when you create it) to a variable and use that to delete it using `delete(previous_handle)`?

Comment: I already implemented that. However I would still be interested in knowing if it is possible otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add a specific tag to the annotation.

```
%# create the annotation
annotationPos = [0.55 0.58 0.6 0.3];
htxtbox = annotation('textbox',annotationPos, ...
    'String'     ,strtextbox, ...
    'FontSize'   ,FontSize+1, ...
    'FitBoxToText', 'on', ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
    'FontName'   , 'Courier New', ...
    'Tag' , 'somethingUnique');

%# delete the annotation
delete(findall(gcf,'Tag','somethingUnique'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I also found that `findobj` doesn't work here. The Parent of an annotation seems to be an AnnotationPane, of which there is just one per Figure as far as I can see, which is like a transparent sheet overlaid on the Figure, that one writes upon.
- If you do `clf`, it gets cleared.
- If you do `cla`, it doesn't.

I found this out because in my application I have 3D axes that the user can rotate, and I wanted the user's preferred viewpoint, and size of figure-window on the screen, to stay from one run to the next, which needed `cla` not `clf`. But I found that the annotations (which changed from run to run) just accumulated on the Figure. However this worked for me:

```
% This eccentric method removes any existing annotations, since they
% lie around on the Figure; cla didn't remove them. htemp.Parent is
% 'the' AnnotationPane.
htemp = annotation('textbox','Position',[0 0 0 0]);
delete(htemp.Parent.Children);
```

Explanation: The AnnotationPane doesn't seem to be part of the usual set of graphics objects, so I "got at" it by creating a dummy annotation and accessing its Parent. The existing annotations are stored in the array `htemp.Parent.Children` (you can use this to list them), so `delete` works on this.

MatheWorks, you can do better than this!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a gander at the [findobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html) function.  As long as you know enough properties of the object you want to find you should be able to return the handle using this (if you didn't save it to a variable already) and delete it that way.