# Modifying textbox string in MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to show some data in matlab figure using annotation inside a for loop. so for the first iteration it works file, from 2nd iteration the data is getting over written. Some thing like the following image.Can you please let me know how can I clear the previous text so that in every iteration it shows correct data produced in that iteration.  [image: here].

My code for this was al follows-

```
fig3=figure;
for i=1:10
...
...
D=distance(a,b);
figure(fig3), imshow(result_images{i},'InitialMagnification', 'fit');
annotation('textbox',...
[0 0.45 0.35 0.1],...
'String',['Measured Distance=' num2str(D)],...
'FontSize',40,...
'FontName','Arial',...
'EdgeColor',[1 1 0.9],...
'Color',[0.84 0.16 0]);
end
```

Comment: You can reset the text in the annotation with the `set` function, without deleting the annotation or clearing the previous text.  See my answer.  This method is also very fast and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient solution is to reuse the annotation via a handle:

```
% create the annotation and save its handle
h = annotation(...); % set all your formatting prefs with any string

for i=1:10,
    % do something to update D ...
    set(h,'String',['Measured Distance=' num2str(D)]); % fast and easy
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to add a specific tag to the annotation.

```
%# create the annotation
annotation('textbox',...
[0 0.45 0.35 0.1],...
'String',['Measured Distance=' num2str(D)],...
'FontSize',40,...
'FontName','Arial',...
'EdgeColor',[1 1 0.9],...
'Color',[0.84 0.16 0],...
'Tag' , 'somethingUnique');

%# delete the annotation
delete(findall(gcf,'Tag','somethingUnique'))
```

Reference: [Delete annotation from figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841233/delete-annotation-from-figure)

Comment: what do you mean by ' add a specific tag to the annotation'

Comment: look at the last argument of the annotation() call

Comment: Hi, Aralo , but it is not working... when I use Detele ..it is not displaying anything..